Is Acts 26:28 wrongly translated in the Authorised (King James) version?
The A.V. rendition is, “Almost thou persuadest me to be a Christian.”
Other translations differ, e.g. “In a short time you think to make me a Christian!” R.S.V.
“In a short time would you persuade me to be a Christian?” E.S.V.
Some have claimed that “the Greek words cannot possibly bear the meaning which is thus put upon them” in the A.V.  The reason for preferring the E.S.V. is that the text is viewed as Agrippa asking a question, but sarcastically, not seriously. See C.J. Ellicott (ed), The New Testament Commentary for English Readers, Vol. II p.169 (Cassell & Co. 1884)
Given that there is no subjunctive mood in the Greek which the ‘would’ of a conditional question would strictly require, nor any future tense which could also serve such a purpose, is there any indication in the Greek text that Agrippa is actually asking a question? Is it not the case that the Greek only has the simple present tense and the plain indicative mood corresponding to ‘thou persuadest me’? Or, is the A.V. wrong?

The Englishman's Greek New Testament has in a little me thou persuadest a Christian to become. Paul's response is I would wish to God both in a little and in much not only thou but also all . . . .  etc Paul's response indicates that the AV is close, at least. Up-voted +1. EGNT.

Although it cannot be categorically argued that King Agrippa did, or did not, put a question to Paul, a key point is this rule of Greek translation: a semi-colon in the text indicates a question. Lack of a semi-colon suggests it wasn't a question.  Even so, a categoric answer can never be given as there were no semi-colons in the autographs.
Before we look at Acts 26:28 it is useful to remind ourselves of the hostility being directed at Paul by Governor Festus. Verse 24 describes how Festus rudely accuses Paul of having lost his mind, that he is insane.  Paul calmly directs the conversation to King Agrippa, then asks him in verse 27:

King Agrippa, believest thou the prophets? (KJV)

This is also shown as a question in the NIV, the ESV and the NLT.  Was there a semi-colon here in the various manuscripts used by these translators to indicate this was a question?  If so, then there should also be a semi-colon shown in the manuscripts used by these translators in verse 28 when Agrippa replies to Paul’s question.
It is my understanding that original Greek manuscripts did not have any punctuation, such as question marks. That is why semi-colons were used in later texts to indicate a question.  However, no question is to be found in ‘The Englishman’s Greek New Testament’ or the ‘Westcott & Hort Greek Text’ or the ‘Nestle Greek Text’.
It is true that some modern Bible translations of Acts 26:28 show King Agrippa answering Paul’s question with a question, where the translators use ‘dynamic equivalence’.  This translation method attempts to preserve the original meaning but adds additional details to clarify the meaning to modern English readers.
The formal equivalence method of translation seeks to insert as little change to the text as possible while still communicating the meaning, even if it means the reader may have to do some research.  In the world of English Bible translations, the KJV follows the formal equivalence method of translation.
Another form of translation method is the literal, word for word translation, such as Youngs Literal Translation.  In Acts 26:27 it clearly shows that Paul is asking Agrippa a question as indicated by the use of a semi-colon.  In Acts 26:28 it places an exclamation mark at the end of Agrippa’s response: “in a little thou dost persuade me to become a Christian!”  There is no semi-colon. There is no question.
Regardless, it seems clear that Agrippa was not open to being converted by Paul.

Ἐν ὀλίγῳ με πείθεις Χριστιανὸν ποιῆσαι
In a short time you persuade me to make me a Christian [my translation]
Comparing to YLT:-
'In a little thou dost persuade me to become a Christian!'
I think I've got the same sense as them without the thees and thous. I supply the word 'time' where they perhaps think it's more literal not to.
It gets rather silly this stuff.
The main grammatical feature of note is the consecutive infinitive. ποιῆσαι is an aorist infinitive and expresses the purpose of πείθεις. We say "persuade to" but the Greek is simpler - its infinitive lets it say persuade to without needing a supporting preposition.

Are there any textual variants? Online bibles mostly don't have critical apparatus which makes them fatal to questions like this. Nestle-Aland (1994) only has a little one, but for something that could change the whole sense they would usually make sure to mention it.
Nestle-Aland don't note any textual variants in the MSS, but they do note the range in the English translations, including this A.V one "Almost thou persuadest" and an even nicer Olde English one: "With but little persuasion thou wouldst fain" but also a simpler one "make me] me to be" so on the one hand probably this problem was on the radar 30 years ago, but on the other Nestle-Aland think it's sufficient to put the other approaches in the footnotes so hopefully it's not some massive doctrinal problem that a literary approach like mine will struggle with.

When directed at major bibles the question "is the translation wrong" usually invites the answer "no you are, if you think translations are able to be right."
Was it a question? One usually assumes the manuscripts were uncials and unpunctuated, which opens this could have been read as:-
Ἐν ὀλίγῳ με πείθεις Χριστιανὸν ποιῆσαι;  < with a question mark
If it matters to something, we could try to track down what the manuscript authorities for this passage are and whether we think the translators have relied on the right ones and whether those ones were uncials into which the translator can reasonably supply this new question mark. But that's a huge undertaking when Agrippa's bald phrasing lets it stand as a rhetorical question anyway without a question mark. One of the reasons the uncials could drop punctuation is that it wasn't being a vital interpretative hinge in a modern language that does rather a lot by context instead of by morphology. The absence of a question mark is unimportant to whether it was a question.
In a Greek text you wouldn't expect a rhetorical question to be indicated at all.
Compare Socrates: οὐκ ἔστιν αἰσχύνη ζῶντα ἀρετῇ = is it not a shame to live without virtue

From reading questions I'm starting to become aware that some people would like for the King James bible to be taken literally in English - whatever literally means and whatever English is. I don't know if the OP is from a framework like that, to be making a polemic contention against all the other major bible versions - but some visitors to the site might come to this question for that sort of reason. So it bears countering.
The A.V. (as quoted) introduces "almost" when the Greek placed the emphasis on how little effort the speaker put into the persuasion and not how close they were to it being successful. That's a reversal of purposive direction and the sort of thing we want to be careful of. If that's not pernicious/deliberate then it's a natural accident of translation - but certainly a translation that has accidents can't stand above the others. And to go the other way and have no accidents produces YLT which is nobody's daily reading bible.
More subtly, it's not quite to be a Christian. The emphasis is on the persuader making Agrippa a Christian. In English to persuade someone to be X is to persuade someone to make them X - - so that doesn't matter much but R.S.V. is closer on that. And that's what you get a lot of: English isn't close to Greek (except relatively by comparison to Hebrew) and the loss of closeness really goes without saying except when it produces actual disagreement (such as happened in the Nicene Creed around "ἰδιότης" versus "substantia" or "essentia.")
For Agrippa this is going to be about whether he's really pretty tempted by this Christianity stuff, or scornful of it.
Whoever wrote this didn't care about that. They have put it in such simple terms that the distinction we want to draw couldn't survive. Why do we want to draw a distinction the writer didn't give us the material for? Straight away that falls into the bear-trap of eisegesis: if for example it's because we want Saint Paul to have been a super-evangelist we can imitate on the doorstep.
On balance, I think Agrippa's ποιῆσαι shows distrust because it emphasises Saint Paul trying to make him a Christian, not himself becoming a Christian. If he was stirred by the evangelical enterprise, he'd have said something reflexive.

Responding to your interest in peoples' views of the K.J.V. in comparison to other translations: I would make it clear that I am not in the "King James Only" camp, those who think the K.J.V. is totally correct. There are bits that are poorly translated, and some downright errors. However, it is far and away more precisely translated than  modern versions, in my opinion. With this Q I seek to find out if that is true, with this particular verse. I appreciate the time and effort you have put into your fulsome answer.

This might interest: the original was 14 syllables, the translations are ~15, the question was 252 syllables, and to answer it I needed 1277. The precision of the translation is the precision of 1% of the information: the other 99% being produced in the shared cultural discourse of reading. I guess I'm saying it's like wanting to improve a nation's sporting performance with better shoes.

This is a textual variation issue, not just a translation issue, and it is not easily answered.

  26:28      ποιῆσαι {A}



The difficulty of capturing the nuances intended in this verse is notorious. Without entering into the lexical problems (e. g. does ἐν ὀλίγῳ mean “in a short time” or “with little effort”?), from the standpoint of textual criticism the reading that is supported by 74 א B 33 81 syrhmg copbo al seems to account best for the other readings, which appear to be attempts at smoothing the meaning. Thus, instead of πείθεις codex Alexandrinus reads πείθῃ (“you trust [or, think] that you can make me a Christian”), which is adopted by Lachmann, Alford, A. C. Clark, though the verb seems to have been suggested by πείθομαι of ver. 26. The reading γενέσθαι of the Byzantine text (E P Ψ 049 most minuscules, followed by the Textus Receptus) appears to have come from the following verse. Hort, who suspected some primitive corruption in the text, suggested that possibly πέποιθας should be read for με πείθεις.
--
Metzger, B. M., United Bible Societies. (1994). A textual commentary on the Greek New Testament, second edition a companion volume to the United Bible Societies’ Greek New Testament (4th rev. ed.) (p. 439). United Bible Societies.



However, A.T. Roberson wrote the KJV translation was impossible.

Acts 26:28


With but little persuasion thou wouldest fain make me a Christian (ἐν ὀλιγῳ με πειθεις Χριστιανον ποιησαι [en oligōi me peitheis Christianon poiēsai]). The Authorized rendering is impossible: “Almost thou persuadest me to be a Christian.” Ἐν ὀλιγῳ [En oligōi] does not mean “almost.” That would require ὀλιγου, παρʼ ὀλιγον [oligou, par’ oligon], or δει ὀλιγου [dei oligou]. It is not clear, however, precisely what ἐν ὀλιγοι [en oligoi] does mean. It may refer to time (in little time) or a short cut, but that does not suit well ἐν μεγαλῳ [en megalōi] in verse 29. Tyndale and Crammer rendered it “somewhat” (in small measure or degree). There are, alas, many “somewhat” Christians. Most likely the idea is “in (or with) small effort you are trying to persuade (πειθεις [peitheis], conative present active indicative) me in order to make me a Christian.” This takes the infinitive ποιησαι [poiēsai] to be purpose (Page renders it by “so as”) and thus avoids trying to make ποιησαι [poiēsai] like γενεσθαι [genesthai] (become). The aorist is punctiliar action for single act, not “perfect.” The tone of Agrippa is ironical, but not unpleasant. He pushes it aside with a shrug of the shoulders. The use of “Christian” is natural here as in the other two instances (11:26; 1 Peter 4:16).
--
Robertson, A. T. (1933). Word Pictures in the New Testament (Acts 26:28). Broadman Press.


There are two notoriously tricky problems in translating Acts 28:26, viz:

There is a textual variant - should the last word be ποιῆσαι or γενέσθαι?
The Greek of Agrippa's question is frustratingly terse - just six words

Actually, the textual variation is less of a problem than it appears because whichever variant one adopts, the sense remains the same:

ποιῆσαι (poiesai) = to do or to make or even "to become"
γενέσθαι (genesthai) = to become

The former is the NA28/UBS5 text from the vast majority of the early MSS; while the latter is the majority of the Byzantine MSS.  Both
The second matter gets to heart of the OP's question.  Here is my literal translation:

In little do you persuade me to make a Christian [of myself]?

The great difficulty here is what does the adjective "little" modify?  Is it "time" or "words" or "argument", etc.  Most versions assume it is "time".
However, the KJV is highly interpretive adding material that is absent in the Greek and omitting others; specifically:

there is no "almost"
there is no verb "to be"
the KJV omits "little"
the KJV omits "to make"


I'd disagree regarding your last paragraph - your points are obviously parallel, so it's a matter of a differing interpretation, rather than addition/omission. There's little difference between "make a Christian of myself" and "become a Christian", and "be" here clearly refers to "becoming". As for "almost", it seems that they understood it as "by a little you don't persuade me". That's not exclusive to KJV, the translators of the Russian Synodal Text, at least, understood it the same way. From "only by a little you fail to persuade me" to "you almost persuade me" is a minimal difference.
